# Dimension that is a subset of another dimension

Tags: ssas, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling

I am trying to create a new dimension in my cube, that is a subset of another dimension. I am working with SQL Server Analyisis Services.

I have a measure that represents the number of employees in my organization, both in brach offices and in the central office, and I have a Location dimension that contains all offices.

I want to create a new dimension that contains only branch offices, so that when I apply it to the measure it show me only the numbers in the branch offices and the total aggregates only the employees in them.

I could create another dimension table with only the branch offices in it, but then I would have employees asigned to an Unknown member (the central office)

I also want to keep the original dimension, where I can see all offices and get the total of employees in the organization.

I understand I could get that result using with my current Location dimension applying a filter to my query, but I was  wondering if it was possible to create a "pre-filtered" dimension.

Comment: are you just wanting partitions? Meaning data can be limited by whatever you identify and then you can provide or deny access to partitions by users/roles?  link for tabular https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230976.aspx link for multi dimmensional https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175688(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: "...when I apply it to the measure..." - what do you envisage this looking like? You can already apply a filter saying "exclude the offices I don't want to look at" and if that's too clumsy you could certainly create a member that just had "branch offices" and "non-branch offices" as a pre-identified filter. Is it something else you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You could add an additional measure (possibly [calcualted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms166568.aspx)) called something like `Branch Office Employee Count` that excludes head off employees.  The name of the measure should make a count of 0 against the head office self explanatory.

If this is something your business often measures I'd take this approach.  If not I'd put a new field in the existing dimension for filtering/etc.